How can we prove that these two subsets of vertices form a regular pair?
My question is how to prove  Exercise 2.2.7 on page 54 of the book T. Kloks,  M.Y. Xiao, A Guide to Graph Algorithms[M]. Springer, 2022.

Let $G$ be a graph and let $X$ and $Y$ be disjoint sets of vertices.
Write $e(X, Y)$ for the number of edges that intersect both $X$ and
$Y$. The density of $\{X, Y\}$ is defined as $d(X, Y)=e(X, Y) /|X|
 \cdot|Y|$.


Definition 2.44. Let $X$ and $Y$ be disjoint sets. The pair $\{X, Y\}$ is $\epsilon$-regular if for all $X^{\prime}\subseteq X$ and $Y^{\prime} \subseteq Y$
$$ \begin{aligned} &\left|X^{\prime}\right|/|X| \geqslant \epsilon
 \text { and }| Y^{\prime}|/|Y| \geqslant \epsilon \Rightarrow \\
&\left|d\left(X^{\prime}, Y^{\prime}\right)-d(X, Y)\right| \leqslant
\epsilon . \end{aligned} $$


Exercise 2.27 Show that $\{X, Y\}$ is $\epsilon$-regular when $d(X, Y) \leqslant \epsilon^3$.

This is my attempt at the proof of Exercise 2.27.  I got stuck on the last step.
\begin{align}
|d(X',Y')-d(X,Y)| &=|\frac{e(X',Y')}{|X'|\cdot|Y'|}-\epsilon^3|\\\
&=|\frac{\frac{e(X',Y')}{|X||Y|}}{\frac{|X'|}{|X|}\cdot \frac{|Y'|}{|Y|}}-\epsilon^3|\\
&\le |\epsilon^2 (\frac{e(X',Y')}{|X||Y|}-\epsilon)|
\end{align}

I have identified a typo in the final step of my calculations, and it seems that I can prove it. Note that $0\le \epsilon\le 1$.
\begin{align}
|d(X',Y')-d(X,Y)| &=|\frac{e(X',Y')}{|X'|\cdot|Y'|}-\epsilon^3|\\\
&=|\frac{\frac{e(X',Y')}{|X||Y|}}{\frac{|X'|}{|X|}\cdot \frac{|Y'|}{|Y|}}-\epsilon^3|\\
&\le |\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \frac{e(X',Y')}{|X||Y|}-\epsilon^3|\\
&\le |\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \frac{e(X,Y)}{|X||Y|}-\epsilon^3|\\
&\le |\frac{1}{\epsilon^2} {\epsilon^3}-\epsilon^3|\\
&= |\epsilon-\epsilon^3|\\
&\le \epsilon 
\end{align}
